# How to change kernel image when booting from eMMc in Beaglebone black?

Tags: kernel, driver, boot, beagleboneblack

I'm booting my beagle-bone black from eMMc with "Debian GNU/Linux 8 BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2016-01-24" eMMc image. I have added a driver to my kernel source and compiled and got uImage and zImage files I need to boot my beaglebone black from eMMc with my new kernel image. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please tell where should the zImage be if I'm trying to run init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh file ? What i mean is should the new zImage be in mmc Boot partition (FAT 32 - file system) or should i copy it to any particular location in root file system ? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The booting of the BeagleBone Black using eMMC with the new kernel image can be done using the following steps:

1. Go to the /opt/scripts/tools/eMMC directory in the Board
2. Run init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh

Steps in command line in board:
cd /opt/scripts/tools/eMMC
sh init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh

Hope, it helps.

Thank you,
Sagar Patel

Source: fastbit embedded academy